# Which Dictionary key save space String or Int32

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I have large data set and I need to `Dictionary` the key entries. the keys are 7 digital numbers, so `int16` won't fit.

I am thinking to save space, since  `int32` could use 32 bits.

```
Dictionary<int32,.....>
```

Then what if I use `string`, will this save space?
Since my `string` always length as 7.

```
Dictionary<string,....>
```

Comment: each character in your proposed 7 digit string would be stored as at least 1 byte (8 bits), so no you would not be saving space at the binary level with strings. Int32 would be more efficient in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's right!! it could be even 2 bytes for a char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Int32` or `int` can store all the numbers with up to 9 digits plus some with 10 digits and needs 4 bytes for this. `System.String` or `string` needs 2 bytes per character plus 2 bytes for a 0 character at the end, an overhead for storing the length (4 bytes) + an overhead for things related to objects, plus the dictionary itself needs to store a reference to the string, which, on a 64 bit system has 8 bytes. The string requires much more storage and is slow to process compared to an `int`.

See: [How much memory does a C# string take up?](http://blog.abstractpath.com/2012/08/how-much-memory-does-c-string-take-up.html)

Use a

```
Dictionary<int, TValue>
```